# Read csv files with a random string in filename in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have CSV files that are named like the following

```
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun2 (2021-11-10 1055).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun2 (2021-11-10 2201).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun2 (2021-11-10 0908).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun2 (2021-11-09 1451).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun2 (2021-11-09 2201).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun2 (2021-11-09 0612).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun1 (2021-11-08 1125).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun1 (2021-11-08 2201).csv
SN00275 Dutycycle_Testrun1 (2021-11-08 0908).csv
SN0000 Dutycycle_Testrun1 (2021-11-07 2359).csv
```

I want to plot a chart of the files based on the date (of the last 3 days). However, I do not want to plot the files with names that do not start with "SN00275".

I have the following code, I would like some help with the naming.

```js
function makeRequest(filenames) {
  return $.get("Folder/SN00275"+"need_help_here"+fdate+ "and_need_help_here"+").csv", function(csvString) {
    var fileData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, { onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar });
    var removeRows = 1;
    while(removeRows--) {
      fileData.shift();
    }
  });
}
```

fdate is a variable with the dates. I decided to split the filename into 5 parts, but I would like some help with what goes on in those two parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know all the files since there is no logic because there are random names. Then, just iterate them and check if they match a regex, for example

`^(?!SN00275)SN\d+ (.+) \(2021-11-09 (\d+)\)\.csv$`

It also returns 2 capture groups: the first is the random name; the second is the number after the date.

Of course you need to replace the date with `fdate`.

Check a test here: https://regex101.com/r/zPrreK/4

Comment: Uhm you forgot a little think: `do not start with "SN00275"`,or I'm wrong?

Comment: You're right. Just fixed.

Comment: I am trying to view this in console and what would be the appropriate command for that?

console.log("SN00275" (.+) \(2021-11-09 (\d+)\)\.csv);

Comment: That is a regex, you have to check if a string matches it. Define the regex (using the `RegEx` class o writing it literally like `/regex/`), then use the `match` method of `String`.